# Generate variables using SimMultiCorrData::nonnormvar1

Tags: r, random, distribution, mapply

I would like to generate random, non-normal variables using the nonnormvar1 function from SimMultiCorrData. This function works just fine on its own and outputs a continuous variable:

```
    nonnormvar1(method = "Fleishman", means = 50, vars = 10,
        skews = 3, skurts = 14, n=100)
```

But when I 'mapply' nonnormvar1 in my own function, I get rows of lists of data as my output:

```
    my_func <- function(sample_pairs, sig_pairs, nnorm_pairs) {               
      return(sapply(1:nrow(sample_pairs), function(i) {
      mapply(nonnormvar1, method = "Fleishman",           
      means = mu, vars = sig_pairs[i, ], 
      skews = nnorm_pairs[i,1], skurts = nnorm_pairs[i,2], 
      n = sample_pairs[i], seed = 123)       
      }))
    }

    samples <- matrix(c(rep(c(100, 100), 6), rep(c(50, 50), 6)),
              ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

    sigs <- matrix(c(rep(c(2, 2), 6), rep(c(35, 35), 6)),
           ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

    nnrom <- matrix(c(rep(c(0, 0), 4), rep(c(2, 4), 4), rep(c(1, 5), 4)), 
            ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)


    my_func(samples, sigs, nnrom)

         [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]    [,9]    [,10]   [,11]   [,12]  
     [1,] List,4  List,4  List,4  List,4  List,4  List,4  List,4  List,4  List,4  List,4  List,4  List,4 
     [2,] List,1  List,1  List,1  List,1  List,1  List,1  List,1  List,1  List,1  List,1  List,1  List,1 
     [3,] List,11 List,11 List,11 List,11 List,11 List,11 List,11 List,11 List,11 List,11 List,11 List,11
```

Ideally I want 12 dataframes of two variables each that I can calculate a statistic over. I'm sure there's something obvious that I'm missing but I don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some trouble replicating your example. I had to set a value for mu and truncate samples to the first four rows, after that my code produced results similar to yours.

```
mu <- 0
samples <- samples[1:4,]
```

I would suggest moving the data generation into a separate function. Also, I don't think you need the mapply function here. To get to the data part return the continuous_variable element by adding $continuous_variable

```
getNNData <- function(i, sample_pairs, sig_pairs, nnorm_pairs) {
  nnData <- nonnormvar1(method = "Fleishman",           
                    means = mu, vars = sig_pairs[i, ], 
                    skews = nnorm_pairs[i,1], skurts = nnorm_pairs[i,2], 
                    n = sample_pairs[i], seed = 123)       
  return(nnData$continuous_variable)
}
```

Having the data generation as a separate function also makes it easier to explore the object that gets returned from your function.

You can now call the getNNData function in your main function

```
my_func <- function(sample_pairs, sig_pairs, nnorm_pairs) {               
  sapply(1:nrow(sample_pairs), function(i) 
    getNNData(i, sample_pairs, sig_pairs, nnorm_pairs))
}

my_func(samples, sigs, nnrom)
```

Hopefully this gets you closer to what you need!

Comment: Thank you! That was a simple solution, but really splitting the data generation up into a separate function made all the difference and it was much easier to work with the output. Thank you!